# Does the existence of an eigenbasis imply boundedness?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

The following question arose while studying the proof of proposition 2.36 in "Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators":

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A$ a self-adjoint operator defined on a subspace of $H$. If there exists an eigenbasis - i.e. a Hilbert $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that for each $n$ $Av_n=\lambda_nv_n$ for some scalar $\lambda_n$ - can we say that the operator is bounded or even compact? I thought that the eigenbasis may allow us to write $A$ as an infinite sum of projectors and that this may imply the desired result, but I am an amateur when it comes to functional analysis...

Comment: What do you think about the case where the set of eigenvalues is not bounded?

Comment: @Paul I guess that we would like to write $$A=\sum_i\lambda_iP_{v_i}$$but you are saying that we need additional assumptions on the eigenvalues for convergence?

Comment: If the eigenvalues aren't bounded you can't bound the operator either.

Comment: For $A$ to be compact it is necessary that $\lambda_n \to 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Would it be of any help to know that$$\forall t>0:\sum_ie^{-t\lambda_i}<\infty?$$

Comment: @Filippo The above condition tells you the $e^{-tA}$ is trace class for all $t>0$. Now, a trace class operator is known to be a compact operator as well.

Comment: @SatwataHans Yes, but what about $A$?

Comment: @Filippo I looked at proposition 2.36 in the book, its not claiming that the operator $A$ is bounded. In fact, the operator they talk about is the generalized Laplacian, it is clearly an unbounded operator. What they want to say, is that even though it is an unbounded operator, a decent spectral theorem can be given, and the operator is actually diagonalizable. In general, the eigenvalues $\lambda_n \longrightarrow \infty$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$.